# Learn LinqToSql or stick with ADO.NET?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-objects

I'm debating what technology to use for an upcoming ASP.NET project.

**Assumptions:**

- I will be using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (.NET Framework 3.5)
- The back-end will be a SQL Server 2005 database (or possibly 2008)
- Code will be written in C#
- I already have experience with LinqToObjects and LinqToXml
- I also have experience with ADO.NET and some libraries already built
- The project is relatively small
- The website will feature about five screens
- The database will have maybe six or seven tables
- There will be maybe 25-50 active users
- Transactions per day will probably be about 5-10 tops
- Minimal personal data will be stored
- The consequences of failure or the site getting hacked would be minimal

**Options:**

1. Write stored procedures and call them with ADO.NET. I can still use LinqToObjects once I'm done populating my `DataSet`.
2. Leverage what I know of Linq already to learn LinqToSql.

**Analysis:**

I already know how to do option 1, but I'd really like to use Linq exclusively. The problem with option 2 is that, according to everything I've read, LinqToSql will probably be deprecated in favor of Entity Framework.

**Questions:**

1. How steep is the learning curve for LinqToSql if you're already familiar with other Linq technologies?
2. Is it worth investing *any* time in learning LinqToSql given that it may not be further developed by Microsoft?
3. Will understanding LinqToSql help me to one day understand Entity Framework or are they too different?
4. Ultimately, which option would you recommend for my situation?

**Update:**

I don't want this to get lost in the comments: marc_s pointed out that LinqToSql *is* being further developed, at least as of .NET 4.0. Link: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40.

I don't know if this means LinqToSql has a future after all, but it does make learning that technology a little more appealing.

One thing I didn't ask in my original post but should have: Are the flaws in Entity Framework likely to affect *this* project?

Thanks for the answers so far.

**Further Analysis**

Here is a list of LinqToSql drawbacks, based on some of the comments below:

1. You must continually update the tables and items in the designer as you make changes to the underlying database. There is no way to "refresh" or "sync" it so that it automatically recognizes changes.
2. Version control is complicated by the fact that the designer does not generate the underlying files in a consistent order.
3. The LinqToSql designer generates different code than SqlMetal.
4. There are issues/bugs involving eager loading.

Of these, item 1 is the greatest concern to me. Even with a small project, change is inevitable. I remember once trying to use the Windows Forms designer to map to a database, and it blew up in my face so many times, I abandoned it in favor of rolling my own ADO.NET helper classes.

However, it does seem like SqlMetal might be able to handle my needs perfectly. I run a command, it regenerates everything from scratch from the database, I'm done. If I keep my database simple (just tables--no stored procedures, views, or functions), perhaps SqlMetal is all I'll need.

Comment: _Will_ be deprecated in favor of EF? It already is.

Comment: **It's** not dead - even in .NET 4, there will be improvement to Linq-to-SQL. See http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is very easy to learn and really fun to use - not messy XML stuff like other ORM's, just a nice visual designer; no complicated mappings like EF - just one class per table, and no surprises - **it just works** ! And it's really productive, compared to straight ADO.NET

Comment: @Marc: You are way overselling LinqToSql.  The DBML file is XML.  I personally feel there are many negative surprises when using LinqToSql.  Microsoft is providing fairly minimal resources to advance LinqToSql forward and they've said as much so I'm not sure why you are suggesting otherwise?

Comment: @Michael, "there are many negative surprises" [citation needed]

Comment: @jfar: A little googling should do it, but here are some:  http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/PermaLink,guid,f1a9b52c-b407-4cbb-9197-4bae289ae11d.aspx http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/PermaLink,guid,78e9dd46-b743-4d10-a541-2593354028ba.aspx http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/162336.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956131/when-i-make-a-database-change-how-do-i-know-what-needs-to-be-removed-and-readded

Comment: @jfar: Another one: http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2007/08/eager-loading-appears-to-cause-linq-to.html

Comment: I support marc_s - LinqToSql rocks. The classes and XML can be autogenerated via Microsoft's SqlMetal tool. Once thats setup, you shouldn't have to think about XML.

Comment: SqlMetal is inflexible and what it generates is incompatible with what the LinqToSql O/R designer generates.  Things like Plinqo and T4 Toolbox wouldn't be as successful as they are if SqlMetal was a better tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LINQ to Sql is pretty straightforward if you already know LINQ to Xml or objects (Linq "objects" are just "lists")...

Linq To Sql is not deprecated by Microsoft, they just suggest to go with EF. It won't be upgraded.

Linq To Sql could be seen almost similar to EF. With EF you could do more complicated things, but at the base level is almost the same (for your site with 7 tables it doesn't make any difference).

For your situation I suggest to go with LINQ. It's fun and more rapid than SP + ADO.NET. Using a ORM in nowadays is almost a good choice. Not using it should be the exception (to me).

Comment: Linq-to-SQL **IS** being upgraded in .NET 4: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40

Comment: @Davide Vosti: "Using a ORM in nowadays is almost a good choice." I feel strongly about this. Not using an ORM nowadays is unacceptable. Use an ORM so that you spend less time writing infrastructure code and more time adding value.

Comment: IIRC, you can leverage sprocs in Linq2Sql too!

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Davide Vosti, but you might want to consider other options, like [NHibernate](http://www.nhforge.org/) (that also have LINQ support).

The current incarnation of EF is not impressive - it creates some *really* nasty T-SQL that takes a long time to execute.

We are currently using EF, but this is the last time I will ever choose EF for .NET 3.5. I'm giving it one more chance in .NET 4, but unless it dramatically improves, I'll choose other options (and LINQ to SQL is not likely to be one of them).

Answer (score 3):

> 1.How steep is the learning curve for LinqToSql if you're already familiar
>   with other Linq technologies?

For the project scope you defined, it should be minimal. Doing simple things is dirt simple, more advanced concepts require some knowledge of how it works under the hood, but again, nothing earth shattering.

> 2.Is it worth investing any time in learning LinqToSql given that it may
>   not be further developed by Microsoft?

I would say it is, its not hard to pick up if you already use Linq techniques. Additionally, Microsoft will continue to support and develop Linq2Sql as marc_s pointed out. Scott Hanselman uses Linq2Sql for his Nerd Dinner project (http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)

> 3.Will understanding LinqToSql help me to one day understand Entity Framework or are they >too different?

I've used alot of Linq2Sql and only a very small bit of Entity Framework, they are similar but different. The basics are much the same, and I haven't been involved in any super advanced use cases.

> 4.Ultimately, which option would you recommend for my situation?

If I were developing a site like you proposed, I would seriously look into Linq2Sql, you could probably get the basics working in a few hours and make a decision if the learning curve is greater than you want to deal with. (IMHO, I doubt you'll find that to be the case.)

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - How steep is the learning curve for Linq-to-Sql if you're already familiar
>   with other Linq technologies?

I would say you have addressed maybe 50% of the learning curve, but it may be more or less, I'm just guessing.  There is a lot more to LinqToSql than just Linq.

> 2 - Is it worth investing any time in learning Linq-To-Sql given that it may
>   not be further developed by Microsoft?

There are benefits to learning any ORM.  If I was going to learn an ORM, LinqToSql would probably be #3 or #4 on my list.  Microsoft's communication on the future of LinqToSql has been cloudy at best and they are obviously putting a ton more effort toward EntityFramework going forward.  Microsoft can always change their mind and you have to come to your own conclusions.

> 3 - Will understanding Linq-To-Sql help me to one day understand Entity Framework
>   or are they too different?

All ORMs share similar features and learning any one ORM will help you understand other ORMs.  LinqToSql does actually share a number of the same features and drawbacks as EntityFramework so there are more similarities than you might expect.  That said, I would recommend learning EntityFramework before LinqToSql.

> 4 - Ultimately, which option would you recommend for my situation?

The best ORM for .NET 3.5 in the vast majority of situations is clearly NHibernate.  NHibernate supports Linq, but it supports it differently than the Microsoft ORMs.  That said, you haven't given a reason that would clearly make NHibernate superior to ADO.NET for your situation.  I would not recommend either LinqToSql or EntityFramework for your situation.

Comment: This is such a bad answer.  NHibernate's superior features sets only come into play during advanced ORM scenarios and are not easily accessible for ones first ORM backed project.  The documentation for NHibernate is much worse than Microsoft products ( although this is changnging ).  The designer and "update from database" support is awesome for first time users compared to mapping xml files.  I think your hammer nailing here.

Comment: I didn't realize that Lazy/Eager loading, detached update, support for legacy DB design, and model first development (off the top of my head) were advanced ORM scenarios.  I respectfully, completely disagree with your opinion.  It is generally very difficult to migrate from one ORM to another so it's important to take care when choosing an ORM.

Comment: +1 - this is definitely *not* a bad answer in my opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Lazy/Eager is in LinqtoSql, based the question there is no legacy support needed, model first isn't necessary with 5 screens-6 to 7 tables, detached update support is possible if required.  NHibernate is awesome but it would only would solve YAGNI problems in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com), it is in a nice middle ground of ease of use of Linq to SQL and NHibernate.

with subsonic you get some of the nice features of NHibernate such as Model first development, automatic database schema generation and support for databases other than Sql Server.

There is also a nice [comparison page](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Comparisons) that lists the differences between the three ORMS